# Digest access authentication on nginx

Tags: authentication, nginx, http-1.1

Is it possible to use *http 1.1 digest access authentication* instead of *basic access authentication* when restricting access to a website with nginx?

I mean this in a similar fashion as on [the nginx guide](http://nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/restricting-access/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [ngx_http_auth_digest](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpAuthDigestModule) module.

That module is not standard yet so you'd have to install it.